# string issue regarding python, basic introduction level

Tags: python, string

I have a person calling a function with three inputs:

1. `puzzle` - so a random word, for example. 'john'
2. `view` - their view of the puzzle (they guess letters and they become revealed scoring points, etc) so lets say they only see `j^h^` (^ represents hidden characters).
3. `letter_guessed` - they guess a letter, so if someone guessed `'o'`, the view would come back as `'joh^'`

But my code just doesn't seem work and I can't seem to understand why, and please if you could do it using my bit of code below, I understand there are many ways to solve it but I'm interested in what I had to do if I wanted to solve this question using a `for` statement with nested `if` statements.

What it doesnt do: it simply displays the view again, the line of incorrect code is result = result + letter because i dont know how to make python scan for the hidden variable and replace the ^ with set found alphabetic letter.

```
def update_view(puzzle,view,letter_guessed):

    result = ""
    for index in range(0,len(puzzle)):
        if puzzle[index] == letter_guessed:
            result = result + letter_guessed
        else:           
            result = view
    return result
```

Comment: You need to explain *how* it doesn't work.  Does it give an error?  Does it not do what you want?  If so, what do you want it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: This is kind of a fun little game ... Now that I coded it up for myself, I just need to figure out a nice way to randomly get a word to play with ...

Comment: @mgilson: you could use the `/usr/share/dict/words` to pick a word

Comment: @xbonez -- brilliant.  Now I have a new way to distract myself at work.  I suppose I could call it hangman.py, although it currently lets me have infinite guesses... (though that would be trivial to fix)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12926600/674039

Answer (score 4):

If the letter is currently "^" and the letter was guessed correctly, you want to add the guessed letter to result. Else, you want to add whatever was on the view earlier

```
def guess(word, view, letter) :
    result = ""
    for i in range(0,len(word)) :
        if view[i] == "^" and word[i] == letter:
            result += word[i]
        else :
            result += view[i]

    return result
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/ZJcqPnB9)

The above `if-else` condition can be further shortened using Python's `true if condition else false` construct

```
def guess(word, view, letter) :
    result = ""
    for i in range(0,len(word)) :
        result += word[i] if view[i] == "^" and word[i] == letter else view[i]      
    return result
```